# Turn off automatic microphone muting

Tags: microphone, voice-recording

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab E 9.6, which I used with the built-in Android 4. Now I updated to 6 (CyanogenMod 13) and since then the microphone is behaving really perplexing.

No matter which voice recording application I use (I tried some of them), it is muting whenever I don't speak for a split second. Of course it turns on again, when I speak again, but nevertheless, this sounds quite weird, is there a way to turn this "feature" off?

Thank you very much!

Comment: How can you understand when the microphone is turning on or off ?

Comment: When I am speaking, I hear the background noise on the recording. When I am not, there is no noise. During replay, I hear constantly switching on and off.

Comment: Have you installed custom ROM of Android 6 ?

Comment: Yes, I did, exactly as I wrote in the question: CyanogenMod 13 is a custom ROM, as far as I know.

Comment: Then it might be the work of that OS to save battery power. Try changing some settings in the OS or communicate with the developer of the OS about this issue.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, I tried it and indeed found an option to turn off battery saving for specific application, but unfortunately, it did not help. Now I removed the custom ROM and reinstalled the factory firmware.